# Book where a gateway in the Amazon leads to different times

Tags: story-identification, time

I think this book was written by a South African author.

It's set in the Amazon, with a gateway to different ages in time. Also time was either slowing or getting  faster.

Comment: Welcome to SF&F! Can you share any more details? Do you remember any characters? About when did this book come out? What did the cover art look like?

Comment: @Mick I took the liberty of submitting a small edit suggestion, changing the tags. I also think your question needs to be clarified. Information about characters for example. A guesstimate about when it was written and/or what language you read it in, and if that language was the original or if what you read was a translation may also prove helpful. Please consider taking the [tour] and read the [help] pages on what to do and what not to do.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to SF&F!  The more information you give us, the more likely we are to be able to help you.  Take a look at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question for ideas to jog your memory.